# What is the background behind the following statement "A lambda is an object without an identity" in Java 8?

Tags: java

Would appreciate any help on understanding below two concepts in Java 8.

**What I know**

1. A lambda is an object without an identity and should not be used as a regular object.
2. A lambda expression should not be calling methods from `Object` class like `toString`, `equals`, `hashCode` etc.

**What I'd like know more about**

1. What difference does lambda expression have to be called as an object without identity?
2. Why exactly should methods from `Object`class not be used while using lambda expression?

Comment: Hey! Could you explain what exactly you are unsure about? This would make the question less reliant on someone explaining the whole thing and more focused on an understanding problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) A lambda is an object without an identify and should not be used as a regular object.

This is not true.  A lambda is a Java object, and it *does* have an identity<sup>1</sup>.  The problem is that the lifecycle is *deliberately* left specified to allow Java compilers freedom to optimize the code that evaluates them.   Therefore, you cannot know when new lambda objects are going to be created, or existing ones are going to be reused.

JLS [15.27.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.4) says:

> *"At run time, evaluation of a lambda expression is similar to evaluation of a class instance creation expression, insofar as normal completion produces a reference to an object. Evaluation of a lambda expression is distinct from execution of the lambda body.*
>
> *Either a new instance of a class with the properties below is allocated and initialized, or an existing instance of a class with the properties below is referenced. ... "*

---

> 2) A lambda expression should not be calling methods from `Object` class like `toString`, `equals`, `hashCode` etc.

As written, that is also not true.  A lambda expression may call those methods.  However, it is not advisable to rely on those methods to have any specific behavior when you call them on a lambda object

The JLS states:

> *"The class ... **may** override methods of the `Object` class."*

In other words, it may ... or may not ... override them.  If you rely a particular behavior of these methods, your application is (in theory) non-portable.

Furthermore, since the instantiation semantics are also unspecified, the behavior of `Object::equals` and `Object::hashCode` are uncertain.

Finally, it is unspecified whether lambdas are clonable.

---

<sup>1 - Sure, a lambda doesn't have a *name*: it is anonymous.  But *name* and *identity* are different concepts.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a lambda is a convenience of doing this:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface A {
    void b();
}

void c(A a) {
    ...
}

void main() {
    c(new A() {
        void b() {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

I apologize for the less than stellar variable names, but as you can see, `A` is an interface with one method. `c` is a method that takes in an `A` interface. However, instead of creating your own class that implements `A`, you can create it on the spot. This is what you call an anonymous class, since it doesn't have a name. This is where the quote you have:

```
A lambda is an object without an identify
```

comes from. The class doesn't have an identity. The reason it relates to lambdas is because if an interface has only one method, you can use lamdas to simplify it.

```
void main() {
    c(
        () -> {
            ...
        }
    );
}
```

This is the exact same as before.

The second part, why lambdas shouldn't use `Object`'s methods, I didn't know before. You should probably have someone else answer this, however my guess is that lambda classes don't look like it extends `Object` directly, so you can't use it's methods.

Comment: Identity and name are different concepts.